# If condition check with python

Tags: python

```
      if not ping_device(ip):
          if not reboot_device(device_1)
              logger.error("Unable to reboot.. Serious issue")
              break
          logger.info("HARD Rebooted")
          if not ping_device(ip):
              logger.error("Ping failed after hard reboot")
          else:
              logger.info("Pinged success after reboot")
     else:
         logger.info("Pinged")
         logger.info("Reboot passed")
         logger.info("Getting uptime")
         sw_version_check = get_sw_version(ip)
         check_upgrade()
         :
         :
         :
         :
```

Here is my piece of code. Now if the **ping_device** fn in the first line succeeds, I have no problem. The else part comes into the picture.

Now if my first line **ping_device** fails, I call a **reboot_device** fn. after reboot, I again call the ping function to check my device is online.

After the ping success after the reboot, I need to get going with the **else** part of the first **if** condition with sw_version_check, check_upgrade() and rest of code traverses as mentioned with :

Will my logic after ping failure continue with sw_version_chec and check_upgrade?

Comment: An `if` statement only executes once. Is this in some kind of loop? Are you rebooting the device that this code runs on? Or some other remote device?

Comment: Yes only once. Before the ping, I have set of instructions to do. After I do this, if the ping fails I'm hard rebooting a DUT and to ensure it is back online to continue with next steps as I mentioned with ":"

Answer (score 0):

You could have some separate variable, say `doUpgrade`, initialized to `False` and set to `True` at any point(s) in the first section where you have determined you need an upgrade.  Then test that variable to see if the upgrade code needs to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using exceptions, they help make this type of control flow easier to reason about and are more "Pythonic":

```
def reboot_device(device):
    if not your_reboot_device_fn(device):
        raise DeviceRebootError('Unrecoverable reboot error')
    else:
        pass  # Or anything else you want to do on success.


def ping_device(ip, device, did_try_reboot=False):
    if not your_ping_device_fn(ip):
        if did_try_reboot:
            raise DevicePingError('Ping failed after hard reboot')
        else:
            try:
                reboot_device(device)
            except DeviceRebootError as e:
                logging.error(e)
                raise
            else:
                logger.info("HARD Rebooted")
                ping_device(ip, device, did_try_reboot=True)
    else:
        pass  # Or anything else you want to do on success.

try:
    ping_device(ip, device_1)
except DevicePingError as e:
    logging.error(e)
# NOTE: DeviceRebootError isn't caught so it will end the program.
else:
    logging.info('Pinged')
    sw_version_check = get_sw_version(ip)
    check_upgrade()
```

Comment: in your_ping_device_fn def under ping_device, there is first "if not"condition. I see there is no else for it.

Comment: @HarishSridharan Yes, the idea is that if a ping happens correctly, then the function will return normally. You can add log messages or other things like that if you wish.